# Problems with retrieving url when href starts with "javascript:" while parsing html

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm making a web crawler and I have to retrieve links from anchors, but I have problems with retrieving them when href starts with "javascript:"

```
<a href="javascript:TreeView_PopulateNode(ctl00_Main_TreeView1_Data,0,document.getElementById('ctl00_Main_TreeView1n0'),document.getElementById('ctl00_Main_TreeView1t0'),null,'r','Ufficio di Gabinetto del Presidente della Regione','100','f','','f')">bla bla bla</a>
```

I usually use the following code to retrieve a link from anchors:

```
urlPagina = "bla bla bla"
href = "bla bla bla"
link = urllib.parse.urljoin(urlPagina, href)
```

The above code doesn't work when href starts with "javascript:". How to replicate the behaviour of javascript function?

Comment: Try it using onclick="TreeView_PopulateNode(ctl00_Main_TreeView1_Data,0,document.getElementById('ctl00_Main_TreeView1n0'),document.getElementById('ctl00_Main_TreeView1t0'),null,'r','Ufficio di Gabinetto del Presidente della Regione','100','f','','f')"

Comment: Maybe my question is a bit unclear...what I meant is that I'm parsing html and I'm retrieving links. I'm not the web-master, I'm making a web-crawler

Comment: Think you can do it in two step : find if href value had "javascript:" ( use search or indexOf methods), then if it is, use "hrefstring".replace('javascript:','');

Comment: @akio I think that "javascript:blah blah" is a function call and "blah blah" are parameters of the function, so I don't think that deleting "javascript:" and leaving parameters alone will work